# Render characters like (') to make it native HTML special characters

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am passing through campaign data to my templates with render, something like this:

```
return render(request, self.template_name, {'campaigns': campaigns})
```

Now thats fine, except that sometimes {{ campaign.name }} is a string that looks like this

```
'David's Campaign'
```

But sometimes while its being messed with in javascript because I am using a `'`, the string can be cut short, inevitably making it something like `'David'`

My question then, how can I pass through something that is native HTML or has special character values that will not mess with javascript?

Comment: is `{{ campaign.name }}` being substituted in the javascript and/or <script> tags? or is it in the markup?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`markupsafe`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MarkupSafe):

```
import markupsafe
markupsafe.escape("My foo's are also bars")  # Markup(u'My foo&#39;s are also bars')
```

Markup objects have an `__html__` method which most templating languages seem to know how to use  (I think django is included in that, but I've never used it myself) -- so you should be able to pass it anywhere you would normally pass a string.

Comment: If I did safe_campaign = markupsafe.escape(campaign) and then passed it to the template, its passed as a markup object right? Then I wouldnt be able to do something like {{ safe_campaign.name }} Right?

Comment: @ApathyBear -- No.  You'd do something like `safe_campaign.name = markupsafe.escape(safe_campaign)`

Answer (score 1):

[Encode it as JSON.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonify/0.2.1)

```
var campaign = {{campaign|jsonify}}
```